# Can I add a document from the file cabinet at the end of a generated pdf?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am using the nlapiXMLToPDF in suitescript to generate a PDF. I have a file in the file cabinet I would like to add at the end of the generated PDF file. Is this possible to do?

```
    var file = nlapiXMLToPDF(xml);
    response.setContentType('PDF', 'formalQuote.pdf');
    response.write(file.getValue());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  To do this you need to change your XML to include another file as a separate `<pdf>` within a `<pdfset>`.

Before:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
    *CODE*
</pdf>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdfset>
<pdf>
    *CODE*
</pdf>
<pdf src=*link to file cabinet document*></pdf>
</pdfset>
```

Comment: Note that the pdf you are including from the File Cabinet needs to be "available without login" for this to work.